# Run CoffeeScript class in browser and in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have a class in CoffeeScript that I would like to use both on the server and in the broser.

For the server I need

```
class classname
    constructor: (@arg)->
        #code

module.classname = classname
```

But for the brwoser I need

```
class classname
    constructor: (@arg)->
        #code

window.classname = classname
```

Is there anyway to make it so that only one file has to be maintained?

Comment: Are window undefined in the server and module undefined in the browser ?

Comment: window is undefined on server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case it requires using libraries like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) and [browserify](http://browserify.org/), but in your case you can simply write:

```
class classname
  constructor: (@arg)->
    #code

module?.classname = classname
window?.classname = classname
```

This code will check the existence of `module` and `window` variables before modifying them.

Comment: excellent!  It works!  I'll look into browserify in the future